# How can I enable field test mode on Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: gsm, dialer-codes

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. Are there any codes to enable field test mode, like band selection? Has someone managed to enable such an option?

Answer (score 1):

`*#*#7262626#*#*` – Perform a field test
`*#2263#` - If previous doesn't work.

Sadly, Samsung used to provide field test display by entering codes in keypad. **However, from Galaxy S3 onward, the service mode *#*#197328640#*#* was disabled.** Only *#0011# is still available.  The worst is that even the Android default testing info *#*#4636#*#* was disabled as well.

And just because this looked very sparse, here's a big list!

For IMEI Number: *#06#  
For RAM Memory version: *#*#3264#*#*
For FTA SW version: *#\*#1111#*#*
For FTA HW version: *#*#2222#*#*
For Touchscreen version: *#*#2663#*#*
To test Bluetooth: *#*#232331#*#*
To display Bluetooth Physic Address: #*#232337#*#
To test secret GPS: *#*#1472365#*#*
To test other GPS:  *#*#1575#*#*
To test WiFi/Wireless LAN of phone: *#*#232339#*#* or *#*#528#*#* or *#*#526#*#*
To display Wi-Fi MAC Address: *#*#232338#*#*
To test Vibration and Back-light of device: *#*#0842#*#*
To test Proximity/Distance Sensor: *#*#0588#*#*
To test Touchscreen: *#*#2663#*#*
For Audio Test: *#*#0289#*#* or *#*#0673#*#*
To launch Service Mode: *#*#197328640#*#*
Hidden Service Menu (Motorola Droid): ##7764726
Field Test: *#*#7262626#*#*
To format the phone: *2767*3855#
To Restore Factory Settings: *#*#7780#*#*
To create Immediate backup of your multimedia files: *#*#273282*255*663282*#*#*
To display Phone Information: *#*#4636#*#*
To get detailed Camera Information: *#*#34971539#*#*
For Software & Hardware Information: *#12580*369#
To display HSDPA/HSUPA Control Menu: *#301279#
To start GTalk Monitoring: *#*#8255#*#*
To get PDA, Phone, H/W and RF Call Date: *#*#4986*2650468#*#*
Displays Build Time and Change List number: *#*#44336#*#*
Packet Loopback Test: *#*#0283#*#*
LCD  Display Test: *#*#0*#*#*
Enter Service Menu (on New Phones): *#0*#
Diagnostic Configuration: *#9090#
USB Logging Control: *#872564#
System Dump Mode: *#9900#
View Phone Lock Status: *#7465625#
Executes Emergency Dial Screen to unlock PUK Code: **05**#
Enables Voice Dialing Logging Mode: *#*#8351#*#*
Disables Voice Dialing Logging Mode: *#*#8350#*#*
Change behavior of Power button: *#*#7594#*#*

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply!!!But unfortunately am not able to enable the most important for my case Field Test: ##7262626##.Do you know any way to work it out?

Comment: @GiwrgosRizeakos they took a lot of this out in newer firmwares, try *#2263#  and let me know. We'll find it!

Comment: Just managed to do something by rolling back to older software version,but is not excellent....Have you managed to use it properly?

Comment: @GiwrgosRizeakos nope, not on any device I have to hand, but they are all newer devices. Annoying.

Comment: Just a heads-up: most of the asterisks here are disappearing due to Markdown formatting. If you see italic, then it means it's enclosed by single asterisk. If it's bold, then it's enclosed by double asterisk. See the [source](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/c86df2b8-2560-4c2c-9345-5f4fdc18dbc5/view-source) to see the correct codes.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yeah I rejected your edit in error this morning, I had too many things open, my apologies for that. I've fixed it now, I'll make up the rep to you next time. This is why I'm not posting much lately, head just isn't on straight!!

Comment: People do some mistakes after all, no worries :)